# Chrome 77.0.3865.90 messes up layout using margin-left: -100%

Tags: css, google-chrome, margin-left

```css
    body {
        min-width: 660px;         /* 2 x (LC fullwidth + CC padding) + RC fullwidth */
    }

    #container {
        padding-left: 200px;      /* LC fullwidth */
        padding-right: 230px;     /* RC fullwidth + CC padding */
    }

    #container .column {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }

    #center {
        padding: 15px 15px;       /* CC padding */
        width: 100%;
    }

    #left {
        width: 200px;             /* LC width */
        padding: 0 0px;           /* LC padding */
        right: 230px;             /* LC fullwidth + CC padding */
        margin-left: -100%;
    }

    #right {
        width: 170px;             /* RC width */
        padding: 0 15px;          /* RC padding */
        margin-right: -100%;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="center" class="column">CENTER</div>
      <div id="left" class="column">LEFT</div>
      <div id="right" class="column">RIGHT</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I support a website that has worked for years. All of a sudden the layout is messed up in Chrome: the left column disappears and the right column appears below the center column. Still works fine in Firefox. The CSS uses margin-left: -100%. Looking for suggestions for a better way to do this? (And wondering if Chrome has changed for better or worse?) Thanks

Comment: Hi Adam, please include an [mcve] - this means in your case we need to see the HTML as well. Stack Overflow provides a handy option to embed your HTML and CSS in a runnable demo environment, just click the Snippet icon to the right of the "image upload" icon in the post edit view.

Comment: If you're just looking for left | center | right layout that's consistent don't use float and whatever your margins are doing, just use flex or grid or even inline-block elements are better.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Chris W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090206/chris-w). That's put me on the right track.
Still curious if/why Chrome changed, but not to worry.

```css
    #container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    #center {
        order: 2;
    }

    #left {
        order: 1;
        flex-shrink: 3;
    }

    #right {
        order: 3;
        flex-shrink: 3;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="center" class="column">CENTER</div>
      <div id="left" class="column">LEFT</div>
      <div id="right" class="column">RIGHT</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```